# python: How can I improve my snippet to parse elements in order

Tags: python

I wish to find all my elements as i wish to find with in a html block and then sort it up so all every tag has it position in my list ex: ('h3', 'a', 'img')

I wonder if there are any better way to solve my problem in a more beautiful way and easier to extend(add more tags).

Ex: So I could send this list to an function with out thinking twice about it.

Here are the result after I run my snippet:

```
[
('text 1', '/url1', '/img1.png'),
('text 2', '/url2', '/img3.png'),
('text 3', '/url3', '/img3.png'),
]
```

snippet:

```
def parse_element_tag(el):
    #<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>
    dict = {'a': (el.get('href'), 1), 'img': (el.get('src'), 2), 'h3': (el.text, 0)}
    return dict[el.tag]

requests_cache.configure('test', expire_after=900)
r = readUrl('http://www.svtplay.se/program')
l = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
lst = []
for el in l.cssselect('div ul.svtGridBlock li div a'):
    #lst.append(sorted([parse_element_tag(i) for i in el.iter()], key=lambda val: val[1]))
    lst.append(
               tuple([i[0] for i in sorted(
                      [parse_element_tag(i) for i in el.iter() if i.tag in ('a', 'img', 'h3')], key=lambda val: val[1]
                      )]
               ))
```

Comment: (a) You should probably show some input (b) this is more suitable for the codereview site.

Comment: @Marcin: (a) The input is the html at the url referenced (b) you're probably right. @user2417865: You're question is a little vague. However, to make it easy to add more tags, make the `('a', 'img', 'h3')` used in the `if i.tag in` clause a variable instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: @martineau I don't really care that there's a url. It would be nice to see the actual input.

Comment: Example html input for 'el' inside the loop:

    <a class="playBox-FloatLeft svtXPositionRelative playCategoriesBox playCategoryLink" href="/kategorier/barn">
        <img alt="Barn" class="svtMBFig-L-O-O-O svtMediaBlockFig-L playCategoryIcon" src="/public/images/categories/kat-barn.png">
        <h3 class="playCategoryCaption">Barn</h3>
       </a>

Answer (score 0):

Using [xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
def parse_element_tag(el, path):
    matched = el.xpath(path)
    if matched:
        return matched[0].strip()
    return ''

lst = []
paths = './/h3/text()', './@href', './/img/@src'
for el in l.cssselect('div ul.svtGridBlock li div a'):
    lst.append(tuple(parse_element_tag(el, path) for path in paths))
```

---

```
>>> for x in lst: print(x)
('Barn', '/kategorier/barn', '/public/images/categories/kat-barn.png')
(u'Dokument\xe4r', '/kategorier/dokumentar', '/public/images/categories/kat-dokumentar.png')
('Film & Drama', '/kategorier/filmochdrama', '/public/images/categories/kat-filmochdrama.png')
(u'Kultur & N\xf6je', '/kategorier/kulturochnoje', '/public/images/categories/kat-kulturochnoje.png')
('Nyheter', '/kategorier/nyheter', '/public/images/categories/kat-nyheter.png')
(u'Samh\xe4lle & Fakta', '/kategorier/samhalleochfakta', '/public/images/categories/kat-samhalleochfakta.png')
('Sport', '/kategorier/sport', '/public/images/categories/kat-sport.png')
('', '/kategorier/oppetarkiv', '/public/images/categories/kat-oppetarkiv.png')
```